# In the primary election phase, there's no live updates of the scores

Tags: bug, election

Just noticed it in the [Code Review election primary](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/election/1?tab=primary) - there's no live updates on the vote scores of each candidate?

Is it intended? Or depends on reputation to see them?

Comment: Funny to see moderators run for moderator.

Comment: @Patrick Why? The diamonds you see now are pro-tems. So, they are kind of prolonging their moderatorship.

Comment: I know, I just noticed the diamonds in their card.